# StructureMap 2.5.4 FindInterfaceThatCloses no longer supported, what is the new syntax?

Tags: structuremap

previously I had :

```
public class PresentationModelConventionScanner : ITypeScanner
{
   public void Process(Type type, PluginGraph graph)
    {
        Type interfaceType = type.FindInterfaceThatCloses(typeof(IPresentationModel<>));
        if (interfaceType != null)
        {
            graph.AddType(interfaceType, type);
        }
    }
```

but 2.5.4 does not support FindInterfaceThatCloses anymore ...

it seems you have to implement IRegistrationConvention instead of ITypeScanner, so the Process method syntax has to change too...

Could not find any example yet...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still see the **FindInterfaceThatCloses** type extension method in the StructureMap source (in AssemblyScannerExtension.cs).

You can replace the behavior you require with the new **ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing** method.

```
public interface IPresentationModel<T>{}
public class StringPresentationModel : IPresentationModel<string> {}
public class IntPresentationModel : IPresentationModel<int>{}

[TestFixture]
public class Structuremap_configuraiton
{
    [Test]
    public void connecting_implementations()
    {
        var container = new Container(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.Scan(scan =>
            {
                scan.TheCallingAssembly();
                scan.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof(IPresentationModel<>));
            });
        });

        container.GetInstance<IPresentationModel<string>>().ShouldBeOfType(typeof(StringPresentationModel));
        container.GetInstance<IPresentationModel<int>>().ShouldBeOfType(typeof(IntPresentationModel));
    }
}
```